# Enforcing unique foreign key in Django subclass but not in base class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing a website to host online educational material for a university.  I'm using the following data model:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    #snip - remaining fields involve department names, acronyms, etc.

class Course(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    #snip

class Resource(models.Model):
    # generic class for course syllabuses, exams, homework, and other documents
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

class Syllabus(Resource):
    #snip - fields for titles, URLs, and the like

class Homework(Resource):
    #snip - similar fields to above

# and other similar subclasses
```

Every resource subclass (syllabus, homework, etc.) is associated with one course through the Course foreign key in the base Resource class.  I want to enforce uniqueness of the foreign key for the Syllabus subclass (i.e. allow only one syllabus per course), but not for the other subclasses, and keep the class hierarchy intact.

I tried searching around for solutions, but I couldn't find anything that seemed promising, although it could be my lack of Django experience getting in the way.  I'd appreciate any quick help.

Comment: Have you tried making Resource an Abstract Base Class? I don't know if that'd allow you to define the uniqueness on the subclass, but it'd be more likely than the hierarchical table version of subclassing

Comment: Not being very helpful here I guess, but subclassing in Django is weird and full of gotchyas like this one. A lot of the time the code duplication really is worth it.

Comment: I ended up ditching the Resource class and making everything a direct subclass of models.Model.  In the end, it was a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this : [one to one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Comment: I often use `resources = Resource.objects.all()` or the like to get (and then iterate through) a list of all resources, discriminating them using `instanceof()`; the class hierarchy is really useful for those cases.  I can't see quite how the link would help me, and its examples seem to get rid of that possibility.